# Editar ficheiros word e converter para PDF php

Tags: php, pdf

Possuo um documento e toda vez que preciso alterar uma informação nele necessito fazer todo este procedimento que irei explicar abaixa novamente, gostaria de uma solução que facilitasse converter Word para PDF.

**Problema:**
Tenho um sistema de propostas que tem "templates" em documentos do Word para cada proposta que temos precisa ser alterados dependendo da proposta, estes documentos tem texto imagens, tabelas, etc.

**Resolução:**
O que fiz para resolver o problema foi converter os documentos do Word para **.odt** e depois abrir os mesmos com o PHP e fazer replace das strings que pretendo.

O problema que tenho neste momento é que quando existe uma alteração em um documento tenho que converter de novo e colocar todas as Strings no site certo que demora muito tempo, pois os documentos tem em média 18 páginas.

Alguém sabe alguma forma de alterar os documentos de forma mais rápida e eficaz para posteriormente ser gerado o **PDF** do mesmo.

No início pensei em usar a biblioteca tcpdf mas iria demorar muito mais tempo para passar tudo o que está nos documentos para o PDF, a solução que apresento foi a mais rápida que consegui mas mesmo assim é muito demorada.

Answer (score -1):

```
directory=$1
filename=$2
extension=$3
SERVICE='soffice'
if [ "`ps ax|grep -v grep|grep -c $SERVICE`" -lt 1 ]; then 
unset DISPLAY
/usr/bin/soffice -headless -accept="socket,host=127.0.0.1,port=8100;urp;" -nofirststartwizard & 
sleep 5s
fi
python /home/website/python/DocumentConverter.py /home/website/$directory$filename$extension /home/website/$directory$filename.pdf
```

https://github.com/mirkonasato/pyodconverter

Comment: Olá @Anderson. Tente criar um exemplo de como utilizar, por que sua solução atende ao caso do AP? Na dúvida sobre como funciona o modelo de respostas, consulte [answer]

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta neste momento já uso esse sistema a minha questão não esta na conversao para PDF.. Mas sim de como editar documentos do do word de forma simples e rápida através do PHP em k neste momento estou a usar o STR_replace